# Legitimate appearances of <=> in pre-c++20 code

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, spaceship-operator

Messing around in wandbox I discovered that clang will actually issue a warning if it sees `<=>` appear in C++17 or earlier.

```
warning: '<=>' is a single token in C++2a; add a space to avoid a change in behavior [-Wc++2a-compat]
```

I've tried to figure out how to write a legitimate use case of the character sequence `<=>` in C++17, but what I come up with [all feel very contrived](https://medium.com/@ryanhaining/searching-for-operator-ambiguity-5bb16344b704). The most likely example (imo) involves using a template:

```
struct A {
  bool operator<=(A) const { return true; }
};

template <auto Cmp>
void f() { }

int main() {
  f<&A::operator<=>();
}
```

[live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b98Nk44InyOyRcA3)

Everything else still involves explicitly mentioning the comparison function by name `operator<=`. Is there a more common appearance of `<=>` that I'm failing to imagine which would have motivated the clang developers to add this warning?

Comment: Even if there is no legitimate use case, it is still a breaking change that is reasonable for clang to call out. After all, that's the whole point of the warning: To signal any potential C++2a issues.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm not trying to say it's not a reasonable warning regardless, I'm just surprised to see it this early on, and wondered if I was missing something obvious.

Comment: If there were a non-contrived breakage scenario, I doubt that the committee would have voted in the change.

Comment: @RyanHaining: "*what I come up with all feel very contrived*" The fact that they're all contrived is precisely why 1) C++20 is using `<=>` for this operator rather than something else, since the change won't break much code, and 2) Clang is giving a warning, since they know it won't be triggered very often.

Comment: Is a warning in C++17 mode necessary? The above code would not be valid in C++20 because the the template argument list is not closed. So compiling with `-std=c++20` will emit a compile-time error.

Comment: Probably the question should be rephrased: Is there a legitimate use case for `<=>`in C++17, which is also syntactically valid code in C++20 but with different semantics.

Comment: @Mehrwolf [sort of](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KTISCe8jtgDWNAU1) if a c++20 developer adds a definition for `operator<=>` in that example

Comment: Yeah, since the _operator-function-id_ syntax never names a builtin operator, you would need some declaration of an `operator<=>` for a program like this to be valid in both C++17 and C++20.  Of course, you can't declare one yourself and have it be valid C++17.  And it looks like none of the standard headers declare any `operator<=>` ... yet. But probably there should be some.

Comment: ... and we're back to having to put spaces in template argument lists again :o)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are some other possible syntaxes that don't necessarily involve a template argument like that.  For example,

```
class A {};
bool operator<=(A,A) { return true; }

class B {};
bool operator>(bool(*)(A,A), B) { return false; }

int main()
{
    B b;
    return operator <=> b;
}
```

But it is true all such examples do have the keyword `operator` immediately before the appearance of `<=>`.

The only way to prove a claim like that is to do an exhaustive search through the entire C++ grammar, conveniently shown in one place in Appendix A of the C++17 Standard and some other Standard versions.

First, note that because of the Maximal Munch rule, if the next source characters after previous preprocessor tokens have been parsed are `<=>`, then C++17 and earlier will always treat the first token as `<=`.  The next token could actually be `>` or `>>` or `>=` or `>>=`.

The only grammar rules involving the token `<=` are:

> *fold-operator*:
>
> `<=`
>
> *relational-expression*:
>
> *relational-expression* `<=` *shift-expression*
>
> *operator*:
>
> `<=`

The grammar symbol *fold-operator* is only used in:

> *fold-expression*:
>
> `(` *cast-expression* *fold-operator* `... )`
>
> `( ...` *fold-operator* *cast-expression* `)`
>
> `(` *cast-expression* *fold-operator* `...` *fold-operator* *cast-expression* `)`

So as a *fold-operator*, `<=` must be followed by either the `...` token (which is certainly not `>` or `>>` or `>=` or `>>=`), or a *cast-expression*.  Either as a *fold-operator* or in a *relational-expression*, the `<=` token may be followed by a *cast-expression* or *shift-expression*, which are both restricted sorts of *expression*.  But there is no grammar rule allowing any *expression* to begin with `>` or `>>` or `>=` or `>>=`.

That leaves just the grammar symbol *operator*, found only in:

> *operator-function-id*:
>
> `operator` *operator*

which shows that the keyword `operator` must be immediately before the `<=` which might instead end up as part of a `<=>` in C++20.